# Why does vision gradually becomes dimmer in bright setting?

Tags: eyes, human-eye, light

I don't know if this is only happens to me, but if I am in a well lit room and I stare at one point or just look at one area without moving my eyes around my vision in that specific light setting becomes dimmer. I can look around and everything feels like it is dim and lacks the bright light that originally radiated through the room. So I was wondering how and why this happens? I suspect(I am quite dusty in my ophthalmology) my eyes maybe relaxing and taking less notice of the intensity of the light, if so what makes it do so? As a side note this occurrence hasn't affected my life, I am just curious as to why it happens. Another note response to some of the comments, this isn't like walking into a well lit room and get bombarded by the light and eventually adjusting to it. This is like sitting in a well lit room for 15 minutes and then things just become dimmer and less intense. I've also observed this only happens with artificial light and may have some link to the type of light bulb.

I would like to add that this happens if I concentrate on one area or object. So if I were to read a book or be on my laptop, the light around me would feel dimmer. I suspect it has something to do with my eyes focusing on one source, if I were reading a book and this happens, the words become more prominent.

Comment: You mean when you just enter a bright room then things appear bright and they seem to dim down after a while?

Comment: Answer is linked to expression of proteins and sequestration of those proteins as amechanism to adjust light intensity percived by eye

Comment: WYSIWYG not really, I understand what you are saying, this is more like sitting in a well lit classroom for 15 minutes and suddenly everything becomes much less intense and much more dim and gloomy.

Comment: This is a very normal vision-mechanism, that happens to everyone.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(eye)#Light_adaptation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(eye)#Dark_adaptation. But can't tell how-severe is yours one and is it okay or not.

Comment: There are 2 places of rejecting the background-illumination (noise). 1 . Pupil become narrower (like camera's small aperture), and 2. Changes in signaling pathway in retina. On more light, a protein, *arrestin* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrestin). It inhibits the receptor's activities in various ways.

Comment: Always Confused I feel like your description of pupil becoming narrow might have something to do with this I'll look it up and see, but if any of you could beat me too it I would be grateful.

Comment: There is nothing to beat you since it as a natural phenomena... to adjust the vision. And perhaps the light-adaptation is much faster than dark-adaptation, (perhaps because excess light can do damage). But I can't tell how-severe it is in yours case, so you could visit an ophthalmologist (not optometrist) who have facility to predict glaucoma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaucoma) .

Comment: Always Confused, this is not the case, as the issue only occurs after some time. Light-adaptation is not nearly that slow, so that explanation is invalid.

Comment: I get this too, but I understand exactly what you mean unlike previous comments. Only happens when staring, can be almost blurry sometimes.